# Import model from another project

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I have 2 Django projects with their Postgres databases. And they run on two different Azure VM's.

They are models in each project which is usable by both projects. How can I import the model of Project1 in Project2?

Regards,
Gegham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WSGI.py, add the path of your second project to the sys.path by

```
sys.path.append('/root').
```

In your settings.py of the first project, add `'project2.app2'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'app1',
    'project2.app2',
    ...
]
```

And then you should be able to easily import the models of your second project by using `from project2.project2.models import *`

This is worked for me.

Comment: projects run on 2 different azure VMs